# boost regex to find digits

Tags: c++, boost

I need to validate input, only 2 or 3 digits  should be allowed.

I am not sure why boost::regex_match is returning true for 4 digits scenario ?

```
boost::smatch base_match;
boost::regex base_regex("[0-9]{2,3}");
std::string same_digits("1234"));
if (boost::regex_match(same_digits, base_match, base_regex)) 
{
   std::cout << " It is True!"<< std::endl;
}
```

How to write boost regex to get result like ^[0-9]{2,3}$

Comment: "How to write boost regex to get result like ^[0-9]{2,3}$" — What do you mean? That is how you would write it.... What am I missing?

Comment: Four digits begins with three digits.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also not sure. This is what I see:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/589e6f3729b257b9)**

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    boost::smatch m;
    boost::regex  r("[0-9]{2,3}");

    for (std::string const input :
         {"", "1", "12", "123", "1234", "12345"}) //
    {
        std::cout << std::quoted(input) << " -> " << std::boolalpha
                  << regex_match(input, m, r)
                  << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Prints

```
"" -> false
"1" -> false
"12" -> true
"123" -> true
"1234" -> false
"12345" -> false
```

Note that this is different from `regex_search`. You need the `^$` anchors there: Compare http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a89fe8931d04ad99 to http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a430319477fa3b52